# In the standard Kafka Connect JDBCConnector, why does both the object JDBCSourceConnector and JDBCSourceTask both make a database connection?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

In the open source project called [Kafka Connect JDBC Connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc) there are two classes that I am trying to understand the relationship of, [JDBCSourceConnector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/JdbcSourceConnector.java) and [JDBCSourceTask](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/source/JdbcSourceTask.java).

I can understand why the task object makes a database connection since we may have 1 or more tasks working as threads all polling the database in parallel. What I don't understand is why have the same connection logic in the Connector class when if we want to use only one thread we can use a task to do that?

This is relevant to me since I am writing a forked version that modifies the connection logic. I want to understand whether I should consider maintaining the Connector database connection for some reason that I have not yet identified. I am modifying the Task connection logic already.

Is there a design reason this choice was made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Connector itself is occasionally polling the database for a list of tables that matches the black/white list of tables in the configuration. If the DBA added new tables, the Connector will automatically detect that and start additional tasks to replicate those tables too.